# Roots of quadratic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Show that $\sqrt{x^2-2x+3}$ is always real.

I tried using discriminant of roots $b^2-4ac$ but the test is showing that the root is complex. Though the equation is real for any value of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^2-2x+3=x^2-2x+1+2=(x-1)^2+2 \ge 2 $ for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, the roots are complex, so $x^2 - 2x + 3$ is never $0$ for real $x$.  It's positive for $x=0$, so it's always nonnegative, and therefore it always has a real square root.

Answer (score 0):

The discriminant is **negative**, which means there are no real roots. This means the expression is either always positive or always negative. It's simple to show which of the two options is true.

Comment: No *real* roots